# Choice Field Instance Not Displaying Correct Data But Other Fields Are

Tags: django

I am trying to display a `ModelForm` with prepopulated instance data.
It works fine except for the `ChoiceField` which always displays the first choice given in `forms.py` `('LP')` rather than the choice provided by the instance.

View:

```
def review(request):

   order = Order.objects.get(user__pk=request.user.id)
   form = ProjectReviewForm(instance=order)

   context = {
       'form': form,

   }

   return render(request, 'users/projectreview.html', context)
```

Forms:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

  LAND = 'LP' // #INSTANCE ALWAYS SHOWS THIS RATHER THAN INSTANCE DATA
  DATA = 'DC'
  STATIC = 'SW'

  CHOICES = (
      (LAND, 'LP'),
      (DATA, 'DC'),
      (STATIC, 'SW')
  )

  product = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-field w-input'}),)

  class Meta:
      model = Order
      fields = '__all__'
```

template:

```
 <form method="POST" class="contact-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-heading-small">Please make sure everything you've submitted is correct.</h2>
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" data-wait="Please wait..." class="button w-button">Looks good!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `product` field on the form is overriding the field on the model. Look into using a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)